# Data structure: Two maps that point to the same value

Tags: data-structures

I am looking for a data structure where multiple maps point to the same value

For example:

1. We have an object A
2. We have two maps Map1 and Map2

   var map1 = {
     objectA.attribute1: objectA
   }

   var map2 = {
     objectA.attribute2: objectA
   }

Now, if I delete the object from one map, it should also delete it in the other map.

```
var attribute1 = objectA.attribute1
var attribute2 = objectA.attribute2
delete map1[attribute1]
map2[attribute2] === null
```

In other words, there are multiple ways to look up an object but once it is deleted all the look ups are gone as well.

An alternative way to look at this problem might be:

This is a SQL like row based data structure.

We have an array of objects. Certain attributes in the object can be looked up in a map-like fashion. And the object can be deleted by any of the attributes.

Is there a data structure that will help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

you should use a two way hash. one map keys to object the other maps objects to keys.

### to add an object by key1,key2,...keyN :

insert the object to the first map by the list of keys and add the list of keys to the map by the object, where usually you would use a hash of the object for this purpose.

```
var map_by_key = { 'key1' : objectA , 'key2' : objectA , ... 'keyN' : objectA }
var map_by_object = { objectA_hash : [ 'key1' , 'key2' , ... , 'keyN' ] }
```

### to remove an object by key:

get the object by the key from the first map then get the list of keys from object hash from the second map. removing all keys from the first map and lastly remove the key from the second map.

Comment: Hi, I added some more notes. Would you be able to give me some feedback on whether there is another solution?

Comment: this doesn't change much. I'd still go for a two way hash.